# What would be the best way to use the Trace.Write() method inside of my for loop to print month and future values?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, trace

```html
for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyInvestment)
                    * (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
                if (Trace.IsEnabled)
                {
                    Trace.Write({i} {futureValue});
                }
            }
            return futureValue;
        }
```

I need help with understanding how to use the method inside of the for loop so I can print values of months 1, 10, and 50 months in the format that's in my method.